# "Cannot make a static reference to a non-static method" in Android

Tags: java, android, static

I'm having some issues with the old "Cannot make a static reference to a non-static method" error in my Android program. I am creating a sand falling game (similar to the Powder Game) and I created a class called Control to create a Control Bar at the bottom of the screen with a slider for brush size (that works fine) and a button to pop up a Dialog to allow users to pick the selected element. However, when I call DemoActivity.showDialog(2) from my code, it gives the static reference to non-static error (DemoActivity is the main activity of my application). I also tried changing it to just Activity.showDialog(2), but I got exactly the same error! Please help, what am I doing wrong? Here's my code and thanks in advance:

```
package sand.falling.opengl;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class Control extends LinearLayout
{
    private ImageButton control_button;
    private SeekBar brush_size_slider;

    final CharSequence[] elementslist = {"Sand", "Water", "Plant", "Wall", "Fire", "Ice", "Generator", "Oil", "Magma", "Stone", "C4"};

    public Control(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate()
    {
        control_button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.element_picker_button);
        brush_size_slider = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.brush_size_slider);

        control_button.setOnClickListener
            (
                    new OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            //THIS DOESN'T WORK!!!!
                            DemoActivity.showDialog(2); //Run the element picker dialog
                        }
                    }
            );
        control_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.palette);

        brush_size_slider.setOnSeekBarChangeListener
            (
                    new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
                    {
                        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekbar, int progress, boolean fromTouch)
                        {
                            int p = 32 * progress/100;
                            DemoActivity.setBrushSize(p);
                            Log.v("DemoActivity", "size:" + p);
                        }
                        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekbar) {}
                        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekbar) {}
                    }
            );
        brush_size_slider.setProgress((int)400/32);
    }
}
```

EDIT: I fixed it by adding the following to my Control.java code:

```
public class Control extends LinearLayout
{
    private DemoActivity activity;
        ...
    public void setActivity(DemoActivity act)
    {
        activity = act;
    }
        ...
        //Set a click listener for the button which should pop up element picker dialog when clicked
        control_button.setOnClickListener
            (
                    new OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            activity.showDialog(2); //Run the element picker dialog
                        }
                    }
            );
}
```

And then calling `control.setActivity(this);` from my onResume section of DemoActivity.java! Hope it helps those of you with similar issues!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to call `showDialog` on a `DemoActivity` instance, NOT on the class itself.  The only time you can call `ClassName.methodName()` is if the method is defined as static.  `showDialog` is not a static method.

To fix this, you either need to instantiate a new `DemoActivity` or get an existing one, then call `showDialog` on that.

**Edit:** If you already have a `DemoActivity` instance when you instantiate this `Control` object, perhaps the following modification will work:

```
public class Control extends LinearLayout
{

    ...

    // add an Activity instance
    private Activity activity;

    // set the Activity in your constructor
    public Control(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, Activity activity)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate()
    {
        ...

           // Use the instance activity here
           activity.showDialog(2);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. How would I go about getting a reference to a specific instance of the DemoActvity class. AFAIK, I don't create one myself, Android does it automatically when the user runs my app, so how do I reference it? Thanks for the rapid answer btw!

Comment: Hmm, not sure, I haven't done any Android development yet.  I'll take a look for DemoActivity documentation.  Does DemoActivity have a `instance()` or `getInstance()` method?  If so, that might be what you need.

Comment: Well, DemoActivity is a class that I created that extends the general Activity class contained in the basic Android code. I looked up the documentation for Activity in Android, and there is a function called getInstanceCount(), but nothing like just instance() or getInstance().

Comment: If you've got an existing DemoActivity instance outside of the Control class, you could probably pass it into the Control constructor, save it as a attribute of Control, then use it down in `onFinishInflate()`.

Comment: I tried your edit, and it fixed the error, however when I run my app in the emulator and click on the button, it crashes with a NullPointerException at Line 42 of Control.java:        activity.showDialog(2); //Run the element picker dialog
I'm not quite sure why.

Comment: In case it helps, it says for the line:
this.activity = activity
that it has no effect. I think this is because this.activity is basically just referring to the variable activity, and it sets it equal to itself.

Comment: You'd also need to update the constructor from `public Control(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` to `public Control(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, Activity activity)` and pass in a valid Activity instance when you create the Control.

Comment: Well, I added that, but I don't actually call the constructor, I use the following code:
    public Control control;
    public SandView sand_view;
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //Uses onCreate from the general Activity
        
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //Get rid of title bar
        
        setContentView(R.layout.sand);
        
        sand_view = (SandView) findViewById(R.id.sand_view);
        control = (Control) findViewById(R.id.control);

Answer (score 0):

if the create is called by ANDROID, so you do not create the instance, just put into the create `mShowDialog=this` or `mShowDialog=pShowDialog`

in other words - have the create save the instance value
also you can add a public get to get that instance value.
Then you can access the instance function through the abstract by interceding the getter:

```
ABSTRACTCLASS.getInstance().applyFunction();
```